# awk statements - if not found (grep'ed) do

Tags: awk

My table file example looks like that

```
Name1   xxxxx  34
Name1   xxxxx  37
Name2   aaaaa  59
Name2   xxxxx  90
Name4   Name3  12
```

Name file looks like that

```
Name1 
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

I want `awk` to match `Name1/2/3/4` from Name file to table file $1 and print sum of $3. **If Name is not found print** `0` - how can I do such `if` statement in `awk`?

What I already done:

```
for i in $(cat Name_file)
do 
cat table | awk -v NAME="$i" '($1==NAME) {SUM+=$3} END {print NAME"\t"SUM}'
done
```

Gives output

```
Name1   71
Name2   149
Name3   
Name4   12
```

It's almost perfect - I want to add `0` to `Name3` to get such output

```
Name1   71
Name2   149
Name3   0
Name4   12
```

So much question is: How to add `if not found do` function in awk?

Comment: I may suggest to use `$(<file)` instead of `$(cat file)` in [tag:bash]. First notation does not call external utility. Also use `awk '...' file` instead of `cat file | awk '...'`.

Comment: You mean `for i in $(< Name_file)`? What is the difference between your suggestion and `while read WORD; do command ; done < Name_file`?

Comment: Yes, use `$(<Name_file)`. It is an internal `bash` short cut for `$(cat Name_file)`. So it does not call `cat`, just opens the file. The `read` internal function reads the file redirected by `<file` to  `while`. `Read` can read multiple words to multiple variables or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sg like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=0;next}$1 in a{a[$1]+=$3}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' Name_file table
```

Output:

```
Name1 71
Name2 149
Name3 0
Name4 12
```

In this case you do not need the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) loop around [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). It reads the `Names_table` first then process all lines of `table` in one step. So it is much more effective.

**ADDED**

Or a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (>= 4.0) solution:

```
printf -v tmp "[%s]=0 " $(<Name_file)
declare -A htmp
eval htmp=($tmp)
while read a b c; do [ -n "${htmp[$a]}" ] && ((htmp[$a] += $c)); done <table
for i in ${!htmp[*]}; do echo $i ${htmp[$i]}; done
```

**EXTENDED**

The extended question was to group by `$1` and `$2` (and `Name_file` contains all first keys from `table`, so it is not really needed to process).

```
cat >table <<XXX
Name1   xxxxx  34
Name1   xxxxx  37
Name2   aaaaa  59
Name2   xxxxx  90
Name4   Name3  12
XXX

awk -v SUBSEP=, '{a[$1,$2]+=$3;++n[$1,$2]}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i],n[i]}' table
```

Output:

```
Name2,xxxxx 90 1
Name2,aaaaa 59 1
Name4,Name3 12 1
Name1,xxxxx 71 2
```

Comment: Your method will print sums for all lines, not only listed in names. You should add `($1 in a)` condition to work it properly. Also it would print counts in random order which may be unwanted.

Comment: @Vovanium: Thanks! Added. Actually it was not in the specification... :)

Comment: I edited my original question `table` as I have one more question. As your code loops over for every unique Name_file word and adds $3 - is it possible to distinguish every unique $2 word for every unique $1 word (form groups like `Name1 xxxx`, `Name2 aaaa`, `Name2 xxxx`) and then sum $3 for every group? To get such result: `Name1 xxxx 71  2`, `Name2  aaaa 59   1`, `Name2 xxxx 90   1`? $4 states how many words were merged to form a group. If it is too much I can post this as a new question.

Comment: @PaulGardir: Sure! You can use (pseudo) 2D arrays, like `a[$1,$2]`. Is the `Name_file` array really needed, then? What, if there is a line in `table` in which `$1` is not is `Name_file`? Should be skipped?

Comment: There isn't $1 word in `table` that is not present in `Name_file`. I formed `Name_file` like this: `cut -f 1 table | sort -u > Name_file`. And with such solution `Name_file` shouldn't be needed then.

Comment: @PaulGardir: Then I do not understad your original question! How could happen, that a key is not in `table`?

Comment: Oh, I got it... sorry, my mistake in previous comment. And an answer to your question " What, if there is a line in table in which $1 is not is Name_file?", for example `Name3` that is present in `Name_file`, but not in `table` it should be perfect to have line for it like this 'Name3 "\t" 0' as it wasn't found and `\t` because there are `xxxx` and `aaaa` words in that line for the `Names` that were present.

Comment: @PaulGardir: I added a possible solution to your another question. I hope I interpreted  your comment well.

Answer (score 2):

Y do not need any 'not found' behaviour. You're just not properly initialised `SUM` variable before counting. Use `BEGIN {SUM = 0}` for that.

If you need found/not found behaviour explicitly, do it similarly. First, initialize some variable `BEGIN {FOUND = 0}` then change it some way on pattern match: `(...) {FOUND = FOUND+1}` and finally test it with `if(FOUND!=0)`.